# How to remove and not hide fields element in a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove a field from a form and not hide it because I want the form to retract when I hide the fields my form stays "wide" which is an aesthetic problem.

```
document.getElementById('test_field').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

it works but the form remains large (it only does the hidden)

I tried that but it doesn't work

```
document.getElementById("test_field").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Second code should remove the field, maybe the rest of the code is causing your form to be still wide. Could you please share some example for us to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If display = "none" didn't work for you, it sounds like you want it removed from the server's point of view. In other words, you don't want it to be submitted with the other fields. If that's the case, you can just use `document.getElementById("test_field").remove()`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Earning rep can be hard at first. If I remember correctly, you should still be able to accept the answer, and gain some rep in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this you could directly add a hidden attribute in the field that you want to hide like `<input type='text' hidden='true'>` this would actually make the field like its not even there but we could view it in source.